# Trying to find if any elements in vector are false

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, boolean, iteration

I need to iterate through a vector as long as elements are still false. I was trying to check to see if any of the elements were false using any_of but I kept getting an error in the terminal. The error is "expected expression". What's wrong with my statement?

```
vector <bool> check(solarSystem.size(),false);
while(any_of(check.begin(), check.end(), [](bool k){return k == false;})
```

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis at the end.

Comment: ... and the `while` needs a body to execute, at least `;`

Comment: Generally hard to say without the error, but you are missing a parenthesis (although I assume that's just imprecise copying) and perhaps try making the argument `const bool k` or maybe even `const bool& k`.

Comment: Why not use `std::find()` instead of `std::any_of()`? Then you don't need the lambda:  `while(find(check.begin(), check.end(), false) != check.end())`

Comment: @Qubit In practice you won't see a difference between `bool`, `const bool` and `const bool&` for this case. There is no poblem with accepting it by value.

Comment: @MaxLanghof That's generally true, it is however better practice to use const where applicable, specifically when using STL. Some templates are only defined for `const` parameters and creating a lambda that does not take a const parameter can result in a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

To get this out of unanswered questions queue... your code should work if you just add a closing parenthesis:

```
vector <bool> check(solarSystem.size(), false);
while (any_of(check.begin(), check.end(), [](bool x) { return !x; })) {
    // . . .
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra detail of using `!x` instead of `x == false`.  That was really bugging me.